# The safety of running vagrant images

Tags: vagrant

I have external vagrant running scripts - is it safe to run something like that locally (without risking doing anything externally in production)? I've been using vagrant a long time ago, but it's supposed to be used locally in a dev environment, right?

I have the following `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.define "vmmachine" do |vmmachine|
  vmmachine.vm.hostname = "machine-dev"
  vmmachine.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.12"
  vmmachine.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/machine/init.sh"
end
```

`vagrant/machine/init.sh` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Add repo
echo "deb http://www.somewebsite.com testing main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/machine.list
# Add key
wget --quiet -O - https://www.somewebsite.com.key.asc | apt-key add -

apt-get update

apt-get install -q -y screen htop vim curl wget
apt-get install -q -y machine-server

service machine start

apt-get clean
```

Also, why is it `192.168.x.x` instead of `127.0.0.x`? What is the benefit of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Vagrant can definitely be used in local development. I'm not entirely sure what scripts you're trying to run but it looks to me like running it locally would definitely be an option. I used Vagrant as my local dev server for awhile and know of quite a few other devs who do so currently.

The reason Vagrant doesn't use `127.0.0.x` is because your site is running in a VM on your computer and not locally on the computer itself. You basically connect to the VM through a local IP address Vagrant gives a small explanation about the IP address in their [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html):

> While you can choose any IP you would like, you should use an IP from the [reserved private address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). These IPs are guaranteed to never be publicly routable, and most routers actually block traffic from going to them from the outside world.

So I would say they *"officially"* recommend using `192.168.x.x` though they say you can use pretty much any IP you want.